# Creating a connection between Azure Databricks cluster and Azure blob storage through terraform code

Tags: terraform, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-databricks

I have been following documentation from terraform registry to create a Databricks Cluster. [Documentation - databricks_cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/cluster)

I am trying to create a basic cluster. On the other hand I have an existing Azure blob storage account "my_blob_storage" and it has two containers "storage_jars" and "storage_logs". Inside the first container (storage_jars) contains a folder lets called *jarFiles*, this folder contains a jar file called *program.jar*.

My goal is to upload this jar into the data-bricks cluster that I am creating as a library or spark.jars. I have been trying to search ways on how to do this through terraform code and haven't found any success.

I want to do the following

- Establish a connection between Azure databricks cluster and Azure blob storage
- Grab the Jar file from Storage account and upload it as a library into the databricks cluster that exists in a data-bricks workspace. I am not sure if I explicitly need establish a connection between these two resources.

What are some ways I can accomplish this goal through terraform.

```
resource "databricks_cluster" "shared_autoscaling" {
  depends_on              = [module.my_databricks_workspace]
  cluster_name            = "my_databricks_cluster"
  spark_version           = data.databricks_spark_version.latest_lts.id
  node_type_id            = data.databricks_node_type.smallest.id
  autotermination_minutes = 0
  autoscale {
    min_workers = 1
    max_workers = 4
  }
}
```

I have also tried using library block within this resource and spark.jars block with dbfs an wasb protocol but wasn't successful.

Comment: Did you think about using the `.jar` file directly from ADLS? It will of course require to provide the corresponding authentication parameters in cluster conf

Comment: @AlexOtt no I have not because my requirement is as mentioned above. 
You are referring to using jar tile directly from storage account right ?

Comment: yes, it's possible to use jar directly from ADLS. And it's more secure than uploading it to DBFS

Comment: So how would I achieve what you are saying. I couldn't find any resources that does this.